# How to query kerberos enabled hbase using apache drill?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-drill

We have a kerberoized hadoop cluster, where HBase is running. Apache drill is running in distributed mode, in another cluster. Now, **we need to query the Kerberos enabled HBase from the apache drill**, using web UI. The Hadoop cluster is actually running in AWS, the HBase uses s3 as storage. Please help me with steps to achieve successful queries to HBase.

> Apache_Drill_version:1.16.0   Hadoop version: 2

Usually, to query HBase, we run `kinit` with the keytab manually, then get into HBase shell in Hadoop cluster. We wanted to make use of drill, to query in a SQL fashion easily, better readability.

Comment: I couldn't get any exact document, with the above scenario, from the apache-drill website

Comment: Did you configure Drill with Kerberos? https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-kerberos-security/  Did you tried quering HBase by configuring Drill HBase Storage plugin? https://drill.apache.org/docs/hbase-storage-plugin/